# How can I FORCE my Windows 20H2 to update to the newest update?

Tags: windows, updates

My Win-10 laptop WAS recently at version 21H1 (or higher?).  A few days ago, I noticed that my default application for a file-type of .MKV no longer launched my 3rd-party application. Instead, it launched "Movies & TV".  I un-installed that, but then it
wanted to launch "Photos".  And, that app isn't allowed to be un-installed! (who knew??)

After trying and failing to re-establish my 3rd-party application to launch via that file-type, I concluded it was some recent 'Windows update' that had deleted all my by-filetype default associations.  So, I went into Window Update and un-installed the latest feature-update and rebooted.  But, that didn't change things, so I un-installed the 2nd-latest feature. That didn't fix things either. So, I decided to just choose the
"re-install Windows10 from the local device, saving my user-data".

[That's kinda neat...it wasn't TOO painful...it only took about 4 hours, to tailor the system back to where close to where it was.]

But, now I'm at version 20H2, and I'm ready to (try to) update to the next feature update.  But, Windows Update (erroneously) thinks I'm up-to-date.  It thinks that,
apparently, because in the 'history' of previous updates, it says that I've already
applied these updates, and shows the date in the past where I applied that update.
(Ooops...that history info SHOULD have been erased, but wasn't.  Sounds like a bug to
me.)

Googling seems to hint that there's some 'enabling' update that I could manually download and apply, that could override the faulty history info, and just UPDATE me
to the latest feature update.

So, where and how to I get that 'enabling' update, and what is the name of the one
that I need?

Comment: Download the current Windows 10 21H2 ISO, mount the ISO within Windows, perform the upgrade.  If the upgrade fails post the log from Setup Diag as an edit to your question

Answer (score 1):

That's the "[Windows 10 Update Assistant](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/windows-10-update-assistant-3550dfb2-a015-7765-12ea-fba2ac36fb3f)" app. (Not to be confused with the Media Creation Tool which can also be downloaded on the same page.) It will always download the latest release, bypassing Windows Update.

(However, the "enabling" update is something different. The actual 19H2 and 20H2 releases *themselves,* if I remember correctly, are actually delivered as small updates that just activate features that were already present in the 19H1/20H1 files, only inactive.)

Comment: Unfortunately since the enablement package isn’t in the WU catalog there isn’t a way to forcefully download it. Which means the authors only choice is an ISO, MCT, or the upgrade assistant.  However, what’s more likely, is the update is continuously failing to install due to an incompatibility. I mean the author claims they uninstalled two feature updates and that’s impossible since you can only rollback to the previous version for 10 days.

Answer (score 0):

If you do a Windows 10 Repair Install with the Media Creation Link, that will update to the newest Windows version as @user1686 noted, it will also fix the issue with automatic updating.

I fixed a recently rebuilt machine update issue this way and automatic updating was just fine after that.

Repair Install - 2nd Link on the Media Creation Link page and use the option the Keep Everything.

Comment: Thanks to all who responded. Using the Update Assistant worked like a charm...I'm now happily back at 21H2.